# "sanity init" command fails at "Resolving dependencies"

Tags: sanity

I just wanted to create a new Sanity project. After running `npm install -g @sanity/cli`, which worked fine, I run `sanity init`. At the last step it crashed with the following warning:
[Error Message From CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vylAt.png)

I didn't find any similar issues yet, so I post it here. I also have installed the latest NODE and NPM version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by installing the node_modules inside the sanity folder manually with "npm install" :)